# Is there a function to get all the variables in a given php string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a script which includes a double-quoted string (used to make an html table, if it makes a difference) that incorporates about a dozen variables. Each of those variables is modified by a while loop. I would like to push each set of values to a multidimensional array on each iteration of the loop. Right now I could do
`array_push($my_array, $var1, $var2, $var3, ...);`

but that is awkward.

Is there a way to just dump all the variables in this string into my array, something like:
`array_push($my_array, get_vars_from_string($string));`?

(Obviously it would have been wonderful if the variables used in the script were in an array to begin with, but I didn't write the original and changing that would require too many changes to the structure of the program.)

---

By "variables inside a string" I mean: `$table = "<td>$var1</td><td>$var2</td><funky stuff with subheadings> stuff..."`

Comment: Variables in a string? Can you show an example?

Comment: Do You mean something like [parse_str](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Comment: Do you want to push the contents of the variable or the variable name into the array?

Comment: Can you post the code of how does this loop look like now?

Comment: No, because the variables inside the string are already set at current scope.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Afraid not. For one thing, it's large and much of it is irrelevant to the problem. For another, I don't know how much of my company's code I should be putting out here online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_vars_from_string($param)
{
     $arrfromstring=explode('$',$param);//or tokenize here
     $ret=array();//return value
      //then do the formatting and get the names of the variables,this can be done by some other functions too
     foreach($arrayfromstring as $key)
          array_push($ret,${$key});//this is the part you are looking for.
 }
```

You will understand what i mean by the the tokenizing part I think. The interesting part is the `${$key}`. An [example](http://codepad.org/dYr0IxMI).

Comment: Since you posted an example string in the question comments. I think you need to use preg_match to find the variable names, I don't think explode will work, unless it was a strictly formatted string.

Comment: also make sure you sanitize this data if its some sort of user input

Comment: yah explode is and option here, I also agree with bonez about using preg_match on this

Answer (score 0):

To get variables from string, you can use [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all), but you have to use string not processed by php, but raw line of code that assigns this string to variable.

Proof of concept code with bad practices:

```
<?php

$string_vars = array();
$double_quote_started = false;
$all_vars = array();
$table = "";
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = -5;

while($var1-- && $var2++) {

// note single quotes, this does not evaluate variables but treats everything as string
$table_str = <<<'EOT'
$table .= "<td>$var1</td><td>$var2</td><td>funky stuff</td>";
EOT;
    //evaluate the line as it was earlier
    eval($table_str);

    // since this is is first iteration, let's search our string for them
    if (empty($string_vars)) {
        foreach(token_get_all("<?php " . $table_str) as $token) {
            if (is_array($token) && $token[0] == T_VARIABLE && $double_quote_started) {
                $string_vars[] = substr($token[1],1);
            } elseif ($token === '"') {
                $double_quote_started = !$double_quote_started;     
            }
        }
    }
    $this_iteration = array();
    foreach($string_vars as $var){
        // variable variable to get content of variable
        $this_iteration[$var] = $$var;
    }
    // save this iteration vars
    $all_vars[] = $this_iteration;
}
```